# How can I give Javascript variable in @Ur l.Content method (Asp.net MVC razor)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

It's JQuery code using asp.net mvc razor.There is error in 3rd line.
How can I give Javascript variable in @Url.Content method

```
var hrf = $(".btndiv a").attr("href");
hrf = "~"+hrf;
hrf = @Url.Content(hrf);
```

Scenario:

I'm getting html from database. But I have to resolve (~) tag.
Getting html like from db is:

```
 <a class="btn btnBlue" href="~/Order/Cricket?id=29">View order (A)</a>
```

Comment: You cant. Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. A javascript variable (client side) does not even exist at that point (its not scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to convert JavaScript variable to a Razor variable. Where *Razor variable is handled by Razor engine* where as *JavaScript on the other hand is a client side language running on the client.*

You can store Razor variable as base URL in a JavaScript variable which can be used later.

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")'; //Store base URL
var hrf = $(".btndiv a").attr("href");
hrf = hrf.replace("~", baseUrl); //Use it as required
```